# Combine WHERE NOT EXISTS with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update, if-not-exists

I have 2 tables *params* and *params_exceptions* where *params* is supposed to be updated frequently by an external script.

```
INSERT INTO params (extension, type, subtype, paramvalue)
VALUES ('12345', 'FRNR1', 'FORWARD', '24268')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE paramvalue = VALUES(paramvalue);
```

The purpose is t**hat *params_exceptions* contains records which prevents certain records in *params* to be updated with the new data** (or using the data in *params_exceptions* afterwards for that record).

I've been messing around a bit and I was thinking of combining **WHERE NOT EXISTS** within the **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**? Of course all of the above is possible by using sequential statements, but it's possible that the script would run at the same time and I can't use transactions for now.

I was thinking of the following statement, but I can't seem to figure it out:

```
INSERT INTO params (extension, type, subtype, paramvalue)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT '12345', 'TEST', 'TEST2', '24268') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1, extension
    FROM params_exceptions t
    WHERE extension = '12345' AND
          type = 'FRNR1' AND
          subtype = 'FORWARD'
) LIMIT 1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE subtype=subtype, paramvalue=t.extension;
```

Can someone give me some advice here?

Comment: The query fails? It can provide an example with data and the structure of the tables?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your query is this part:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    --
    paramvalue = t.extension ;
```

The alias `t` is not visible in that part of the query.

However, assuming that the two values, the one to be inserted in the `params.extension` column (`12345`) and the one checked against the `params_extensions` column (`WHERE t.extension = '12345'`)  are the same, then you you can use the `VALUES (extension)` in the `UPDATE` part:

Several other improvements can be made:

- no need for a derived table (`tmp`), you can use the internal `dual` table.
- the `UPDATE subtype = subtype` is redundant
- the inetger values (eg. `12345`) need not to be passed quoted. They are not string literals, they are integer values.

The statement becomes:

```
INSERT INTO params 
  (extension, type, subtype, paramvalue) 
SELECT 1234567, 'TEST', 'TEST2', '24268'
FROM dual 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ( SELECT 1  
    FROM params_exceptions t     
    WHERE extension = 1234567
      AND type = 'FRNR1' 
      AND subtype = 'FORWARD' 
  ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
  paramvalue = VALUES (extension) ;
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see your reply at first. Thanks for improvements as well!

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at how this runs.  (Keep in mind that the `NOT EXISTS` is in the `SELECT`.)

```
INSERT ...
    SELECT ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

First, it performs the `SELECT`, which delivers some number of rows, possibly zero.  (Note that the `NOT EXISTS` may cause it to deliver zero rows.)

Second, each of those rows (if any) is checked for duplicates in any UPDATE key.  If no dup, it is inserted; if dup, then `ON DUPLICATE KEY` kicks in and it does an `UPDATE`.

Given that understanding, you should be able to answer your own question, plus any variants you have not yet mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up creating the following trigger:

```
DECLARE paramvalue_ VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS params_temp(extension integer, type varchar(50), subtype varchar(50), paramvalue varchar(50), active integer, PRIMARY KEY (`extension`,`type`,`subtype`), UNIQUE KEY `extension_type` (`extension`,`type`));
DELETE FROM params_temp;

INSERT INTO params_temp(extension, type, subtype, paramvalue, active) VALUES (NEW.extension, NEW.type, NEW.subtype, NEW.paramvalue, NEW.active);

INSERT INTO params_temp(extension, type, subtype, paramvalue, active)
SELECT extension, type, subtype, paramvalue, active FROM params_exceptions WHERE extension = NEW.extension AND subtype = NEW.subtype AND type = NEW.type
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE paramvalue=params_exceptions.paramvalue;

SELECT paramvalue INTO paramvalue_ FROM params_exceptions WHERE extension = NEW.extension AND subtype = NEW.subtype AND type = NEW.type;
IF paramvalue_ != "" THEN
IF OLD.paramvalue != paramvalue_ THEN
  SET NEW.paramvalue = paramvalue_;
ELSE
    SET msg = "Update overriden.";
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
END IF;
END IF;
```